# Change Contextual Action Bar Overflow Style

Tags: android

I would like to change the style (text and/or background colours) of the overflow area of the contextual action bar.

At present the text colour is taken from android:textColor in the current theme, but I want to use a different colour for the overflow dropdown.

I can change the background colour of the CAB using android:actionModeBackground, but not the overflow area.

My style currently looks like this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#3e3e3e</item>

</style>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: please put your some code like style.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following item

```
   <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/LStyled.PopupMenu.OverflowMenu</item>
```

And define the style LStyled.PopupMenu.OverflowMenu

```
<style name="LStyled.PopupMenu.OverflowMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
  <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/bground</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: Thank you. Just what I was looking for